# What is this mushroom that only grows next to my tomato seedlings?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, symbiosis

So far something like ten out of fifty seedlings (20%) have had this mushroom grow right next to a tomato seedling and nowhere else in the planters.
The black gooey caps are between a peppercorn and a small pea in size. They only seem to grow at night and collapse within a couple of hours after
I have removed the glass jar cover in the morning. The jars are used to keep out the slugs at night. What type of mushroom is this and is this a symbiotic relationship?
[image]

Comment: (Answering my own question from three FB remarks a friend of mine received):                                                                                           ...this is a pin mold fruiting body...
...deliquesced Coprinoid...
...genus Coprinopsis...